# how to display single line data in to multiple line in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have one data field that contains multiple values like this

```
1[]abc, 2[]xyz, 3[]aaaa aa, 4 []xxxx xxxx, 5 []zy lae, 6[]alk jnl, 7[]alki, 8[]12345, 9[]abc abcd abcde, 10[] xyza xyza xyza ,
11[] xyzb xyzb xyzb ,12[] xyzc xyzd xyze, 13[] xyza xyza xyza , 14[] xyza xyza xyza , 15[] xyza xyza xyza ,
```

I want to output after a newline after 5 values

```
1[]abc, 2[]xyz, 3[]aaaa aa, 4 []xxxx xxxx, 5[] zy lae,  
6[]alk jnl, 7[]alki, 8[]12345, 9[]abc abcd abcde, 10[] xyza xyza xyza ,  
11[] xyzb xyzb xyzb ,12[] xyzc xyzd xyze, 13[] xyza xyza xyza , 14[] xyza xyza xyza ,15[] xyza xyza xyza ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things-

First pass the values with **break** tag like this:

1[]abc, 2[]xyz, 3[]aaaa aa, 4 []xxxx xxxx, 5 []zy lae,`<BR>` 6[]alk jnl, 7[]alki, 8[]12345, 9[]abc abcd abcde, 10[] xyza xyza xyza ,`<BR>`
11[] xyzb xyzb xyzb ,12[] xyzc xyzd xyze, 13[] xyza xyza xyza , 14[] xyza xyza xyza , 15[] xyza xyza xyza ,

Secondly go to paragraph tab of Format Editor for that area and change the text Interpretation from **none** to **HTML Text**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7cPO.png)